# Where is {{ content }} located in the repository of a forked Jekyll repository for GitHub Pages?

Tags: html, github, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

This is a code snippet located in `default.html`, where it is located in the `master` folder of the repository.

```
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper-masthead">
      <div class="container">
        <header class="masthead clearfix">
          <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/" class="site-avatar"><img src="{{ site.avatar }}" /></a>

          <div class="site-info">
            <h1 class="site-name"><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/">{{ site.name }}</a></h1>
            <p class="site-description">{{ site.description }}</p>
          </div>

          <nav>
            <!-- <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/test">Test</a> -->
            <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/">Blog</a>
            <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/about">About</a>
          </nav>
        </header>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="main" role="main" class="container">
      {{ content }}
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper-footer">
      <div class="container">
        <footer class="footer">
          {% include svg-icons.html %}
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>

    {% include analytics.html %}
  </body>
```

As you can see, there's a Liquid tag called `{{ content }}` in the center `<div>` tag.

```
<div id="main" role="main" class="container">
  {{ content }}
</div>
```

I am confused on where that Liquid tag is pointing to. I'm looking around in the [tutorial here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/08/01/build-blog-jekyll-github-pages/), but it didn't say anything about `{{ content }}`, what it does, and how it is used.

Could anyone tell me about this, and if possible, where can I find more info on `{{ content }}` and how it should be used? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the content of a page or post or of another layout.

eg :

- index.html content is directly injected in _layouts/default.html
- about.md is injected in _layouts/page.html with itself is injected in _layouts/default.html

Just read the page/post front matter variable `layout` to know which layout is used.

Comment: Now I understand. The Jekyll docs should have this added to the `Front Matter` section, but I don't know where to suggest to add this in. It was confusing at first when I started using Jekyll.